# Monitoring network traffic on a multi interface Ubuntu server from the eyes of your provider

Tags: ubuntu, network-monitoring

I tried `vnstat` and `bmon` as network monitoring tools to verify the bandwidth usage which my service provider is billing monthly. The number I reach is roughly 2 times greater than what they report. Now, I am investigating to see where is this offset coming from. Initially I think it maybe because of internal communications between my multiple interfaces.

Inside my server I have 5 interfaces: `eno5`, `eno6`, `eno7`, `eno8` on 1G ports and `ens3f0` on 10G port. These interfaces communicate with each other through a stunnel service. For example the stunnel service accepts connections on `eno5` and binds remote connections to `eno6`. So there will be some traffic between `eno5` and `eno6` that my service provider is never aware of. Am I right?

I think the network monitoring tools I mentioned above measure the inbound/outbound connections to an interface and they cannot really differentiate traffic that is going out of my server from the one moving inside.

If you think this is the only possible senario please tell me if you know of a tool that can make this measurement I want. If you think the offset might be because of another scenario please explain that.

Could this happen on a single interface server because of communications between `eth0` and `lo` ?

Comment: Ask your provider how they measure and calculate your bandwidth usage and if there are possibly sources/destinations/services/protocols that might be excluded from usage charges (they may only charge inbound and not outbound traffic, exclude classes of "internal" traffic)

Comment: @HBruijn Yes, they only charge inbound, but they report full traffic and I compare my counterpart number to theirs. The question is when I measure traffic on one of my server's interfaces, will traffic transferred to another interface of the same server be included? If yes, how to exclude it.